# Mouse right-click stopped working

Tags: mouse, corsair

I just ran a game on my pc which I think the pc is slightly below the minimum specs for. Suddenly right-click stopped working on my mouse. I feel like this is not a coincidence. I've googled how to fix right-click not working and tried both restarting Windows Explorer and uninstalling the device and restarting the pc, both to no avail. I've tried the mouse on another pc and it it doesn't work on that one either. There have been 2 or 3 times where right-clicking has actually worked, but mostly not. Just wondering if anyone else might  have any idea  how I might fix this problem? The mouse is a wired Corsair Scimitar Pro.

Comment: `I've tried the mouse on another pc and it it doesn't work on that one either` ... doesn't that tell you something about the mouse?

Comment: Just to clarify, the mouse works fine other than right-click. Right-click has stopped working and it stopped working when I was running a program that the pc has struggled with before, so I believe that is the cause. It's never caused the mouse to stop working properly before but I believe it has done this time. Nevertheless, I don't think the problem is physical.

Comment: *so I **believe** that is the cause*, your belief is simply misguided. A game/Windows cannot change stuff on your mouse, and certainly not simply by being overworked. You have no way of *knowing* if it's physical. You *don't **think** the problem is physical*, based on what? Seems like simply wishful thinking without any reason to it.

Comment: Given that the mouse has been working fine for years and then started to malfunction precisely when I ran the application which has repeatedly caused the pc to freeze in the past, it's clear to me that this is the cause of the issue. It's just too much to be a coincidence. It's not wishful thinking. I have nothing to gain if the mouse problem is as I say. I'm just stating my view.

Comment: Mouse buttons sometimes break or become unreliable. They're just mechanical switches with a limited lifetime. Try a different mouse and see if it has the same problem.

Comment: @StarCat I mean ok it is technically possible that of all the times during the last year or 2 or more that the mechanics of the mouse could have become flawed, it happened precisely during the 3 mins in all that time that I was using a game and app which I hadn't used at all for the rest of all that time, but to me it seems to much to be a coincidence, ergo I don't think the problem is mechanical. I have tried another mouse and that works ok, but it's a much less complicated mouse. Its interaction with the pc is much less complex and I wasn't using it whilst playing the said game and app.

Comment: Coincidences do happen. As someone else said: correlation does not imply causation. Does your mouse come with software that can permanently remap or disable its buttons?

Comment: @StarCat you can definitely remap the buttons so yes I’m sure they can also be disabled. Why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears the problem may just be that I now have to press the button harder than I used to i.e. it’s become less sensitive due to ‘wear and tear’ and so the solution is to buy a new mouse!

Answer (score 2):

If the mouse right-click didn't work on a 2nd PC either, that rules out any possibility of it being caused by the game or by Windows.

It's either a hardware failure (I guess the game has some terrifying monster, and you needed to obliterate it quickly, so you yanked the mouse... ), or a mouse firmware issue.

I'd advise you to reach out to Corsair support about it.

If you want to try, you can also try changing the firmware (try both upgrading it if it's not up-to-date, and/or downgrading it to something older) on the mouse.

Comment: 'If the mouse right-click didn't work on a 2nd PC either, that rules out any possibility of it being caused by the game or by Windows.' I disagree. It's perfectly plausible that running a game that caused the pc to malfunction has also resulted in the malfunction of the mouse and given that the mouse has been running fine for years and started malfunctioning precisely when I ran the application which has repeatedly caused the pc to freeze in the past, it's clearly the cause of the issue. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: It's not plausible! Correlation is not causation, especially when it's simply a one time occurrence (it happened one time that the mouse failed, and now it's broken). And even more so when based on any conventional wisdom on how a computer interacts with a mouse/peripheral, which is that the computer can't do anything on the mouse (the mouse does things and the computer interprets it) except if you run a firmware update on the mouse.

Comment: Ok well we disagree on this. I may not be able to give you a technical explanation of why this should have happened but I'm telling you it did! Also, not sure what you mean by this: 'it happened one time that the mouse field, and now it's broken'.

Comment: Typo, it meant to read *failed. What I meant to explain is that despite it not working almost "every time" since then, the issue is still something that happened once (when the mouse failed)

Comment: Ah ok. Yes I believe some event or events occurred when running the game and app that has caused the mouse to fail. It may have been a single event. Not sure on that.

Comment: You can't explain technically why it might have happened because of this, while I actually explained to you technically why it couldn't have happened because of this. Hardware quite often fail after some years of being used, and as you note yourself the same issues with the game didn't cause this any time until now.

Comment: *"I believe some event occurred when running the game and app that has caused the mouse to fail. It may have been a single event."*, the issue with that logic though is that it's actually 100% possible to be a coincidence (and your "feel", "belief', or "thought" does not change the basic idea that *Correlation is not causation* (especially with no way of technically having one with the other)

Comment: The game has recently been updated though. This is the 1st time I've run it on this pc since then. You did give an explanation of why you don't think my assertion can be correct but I still disagree. The timing is just too much to be a coincidence in my view. If event A happens and then event B happens at precisely the same time in a context such as this, the reasonable conclusion is that there is a connection between the 2. Remember what Sherlock Holmes says: "How long will you disobey my maxims? When you've eliminated what's impossible, what remains, however improbable, must be the truth."

Comment: Correlation is not causation = Reason. "too much to be a coincidence" = fallacy.

Comment: *"When you've eliminated what's impossible, what remains, however improbable, must be the truth"*, perhaps. But you didn't/can't eliminate any of the other (I gave two) possibilities when the improbable one is actually more like impossible.

Comment: Yeah my Sherlock Holmes quote wasn't necessarily entirely appropriate. Nevertheless, I'm still convinced of what I say. I mean you must accept it would at least be extremely unlucky for this event to have occurred at all times it could have occurred in the last year or maybe even 2 years or more, exactly during the 3 mins or so I happen to have the game and app which have repeatedly caused the pc to malfunction back when I was still using them: as in, every single time I played the game the pc would freeze. If no connection, incredibly unlucky that they happened at precisely the same time.

Comment: I totally do not accept that, it's an argument of personal belief, feeling, anecdote, and emotion rather than objective data or sound logic. And the bad thing here is that you actually might've been able to fix it yourself with my firmware suggestion, which is 50% more possible than what you suggest, and you won't even entertain that.

Comment: I already tried updating the firmware before when I was having problems with the version I was using, but the new firmware didn't seem to work. I then made some adjustments to the pc and did some research and managed to get the old version working again. My argument has nothing to do with emotion though. Obviously it is upsetting to find one's beloved mouse isn't working but I don't think this is causing me to cleave to a fallacious belief.  I don't believe that feelings are contrary to logic. For me there is no conflict. It's perfectly logical to listen to one's feelings.

Comment: Furthermore, I think I'm right in saying you don't even need the firmware installed to get left and right click working. This is a 17-button gaming mouse, as you may know and I think you only need the firmware in order to configure the extra buttons, if I'm not mistaken. I mean I pretty sure I don't have the firmware on the other pc.

Comment: Also, there was no yanking involved! I was just building an Arena deck in Hearthstone using Heartharena companion. This PC is very old now and has had some issues.

Comment: (The yanking was a joke.) **Firmware** isn't the program (drivers or modification application like iCUE) running on the computer (that you don't need) it's the code running on the mouse itself (you update/downgrade it through the computer with the iCUE program, but the firmware code is on the mouse and gives it its brains.)

Comment: Hmm it seems that the problem may be mechanical after all. It works when I press the button quite hard. I seem to have to press the button harder than I used to though and it does seem odd that this happened when using the game I mentioned, but maybe it was a coincidence or even after all or even that the while problem was just a figment of my imagination. I don't think the latter though, so maybe the former. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for the clarification about firmware. I do recall being aware that firmware was separate as you say at some point in the past actually.